# Problem setting MSDTC on client computer

Tags: windows, msdtc

I created an application that is making use of MSDTC (to open a transaction on multiple databases within the same MS SQL server), our local environment was setup successfully and both DTCPing, DTCTester and the application work. However when it came to deployment I encountered issues when setting up the client computer to make use of the server's coordinator.

On Client site I have tried the following:

- DTC Ping passed successfully
- Setting Coordinator to the server one results into the following error "The specified remote host machine does not exist"
- I am able to ping the server using host name

When I tried running DTC tester, it output the following:

```
Executed: dtctester.exe
DSN:  accdim
User Name: sa
Password: <hidden>
tablename= #dtc16397
Creating Temp Table for Testing: #dtc16397
Warning: No Columns in Result Set From Executing: 'create table #dtc16397 (ival int)'
Initializing DTC
DtcGetTransactionManager failed: 8004d01b
DtcGetTransactionManager Call Error: Indicates unable to connect to the transaction manager, or the transaction manager is unavailable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended out being a domain policy issue, the computer was moved to an other group and MSDTC was registered and working successfully.